# Haskell length toInteger Conversion

Tags: haskell, integer, int, type-conversion, tuples

I have the following pair of Integers:

```
maxCollatz :: (Integer, Integer)
maxCollatz = (head $ maximum (map collatzList [1..500]), length $ maximum (map collatzList [1..500]))
```

Since I am a newbie, I don't know how to use either `fromIntegral` or `toInteger` to convert `length` to Integer. I know that length must be finite, but since the range of the "function" can be quite big, I am inclined to use `(Integer, Integer)`.

Again, my question is - how to convert `length` to `Integer` from `Int` using `fromIntegral` or `toInteger`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems : first your code doesn't do what you think it does, second just converting the length to an integer is completely useless...

1) Your code is erroneous since `maximum` doesn't select the longest list. `maximum` works with `Ord` instances and select the greatest according to the `compare` method for this type. For Int and Integer, the order may be obvious but for lists it is not so. The traditional way to order list is the lexicographic order (which is used in dictionaries if you consider words to be list of characters) : "[] < y:_" and "x:xs < y:ys" iff x < y or (x == y and xs < ys).

So your code will simply give you the collatzList that start with the biggest number, that is `[500, 250, ...]`.

2) Converting your length to `Integer` is nice but it's too late : if it was computed with an `Int`, it won't restore the correct value, a list of length `(maxBound :: Int) + 1` will get a computed length of `(minBound :: Int)` then this `Int` will be converted to an `Integer` of the same value...

What you want is to compute the length directly with `Integer`s which you can do with `Data.List.genericLength`.

---

That said, you really don't need to use `Integer`, especially if you're on a 64-bit GHC (very likely, check with `ghc -e "maxBound :: Int"` on the CLI). Collatz won't go over a 64-bit `Int` for reasonable starting numbers.

As for `maximum`, I suggest you investigate `maximumBy`, `comparing` and `zip` to get code that do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have found it:

```
maxCollatz :: (Integer, Integer)
maxCollatz = (head $ maximum (map collatzList [1..500]), toInteger $ length $ maximum (map collatzList [1..500]))
```

Just add `toInteger $` before length.